# React native supports to integrate with Android auto or not

Tags: android, react-native, apk, android-auto, carplay

I am trying to develop a carplay application using react native application

## Facing Issues:

1. I have developed a react native application, but it is not getting integrated with the android auto application.
2. I have a query that react native supports the generated signed apk to get integrated with Android Auto or not

Thanks in Advance.!!

Answer (score 2):

When a user plugs an Android mobile device into a dashboard that supports Android Auto, the system requests a list of installed apps that include app manifest entries to indicate they support services for Android Auto and how to access them. The manifest references a separate XML configuration file, that will control what Auto features your app has access to. More details in the Android developer docs for Auto [here](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/start#auto-metadata)

You would need to have the manifest that references the xml configuration file for it to be recognized. Currently however, only apps supporting [Messaging or Media](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/)  will be approved on the Auto platform for live publishing.

If you’re writing a media app, you’ll also need to define a service that provides a browsable list of the audio tracks, callbacks to handle the playback controls, as well as handle audio playback requests before it will be approved or appear in the list of apps within the media facet of the (Desktop) Head Unit.